# How can I use a DelegatingHandler to wrap a generic type returned by Aspnet WebApi?

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api

I have a class `Response<T>`, that is supposed to wrap all MVC Web Api calls. T is the actual payload value for the response (say, a business object or a collection of such). I would like to build this class using a Handler that wraps all the messages in exception arrays and other info that needs to be sent back to the caller. The problem is, how do I create one of these `Response<T>`'s without knowing the type of "`T`", and without a generic interface for `DelegatingHandler`?

I am trying to create a response with `HttpRequest.CreateResponse()` using the pattern in this article:

http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/wrapping-asp.net-web-api-responses-for-consistency-and-to-provide-additional-information

Comment: Can you add a non-generic base type?

Comment: If by "add", you mean "use a different type instead that is not generic", the answer is no. User SDKs are already bound against this object and it would take a redesign to shake it.

Comment: No; I mean make it inherit a new base type or interface.  That isn't a breaking change.

Comment: OK so make Response<T> inherit Response? But then doesn't the Value property become type object? And will it serialize/deserialize the same?

Comment: Also, the class is provided in an assembly shared by the web api and the sdk. Adding a new class to this assembly, how do I prevent its use as a replacement?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: In other words, this new Response class is now being shipped to users of the SDK, but they have no use for it.

Comment: You can make it `internal`.

Comment: duh good call thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a non-generic `IResponse` base interface that exposes `object Result` (`Response<T>` should implement this explicitly).

You can then use that type in your handler.